# Multiple Context Time-Series Variable Selection

Tags: time-series, feature-selection, stationarity

I'm working with a time-series data set where I'm given an entities', quarterly, total balance (measured in billions of dollars) over 15 years (dependent variable). I'm also given 16 explanatory variables to choose from which are mainly macroeconomic variables like: GDP growth rate, unemployment rate, inflation rate, stock indices and various interest rates.

I started my analysis by just plotting each variable (both dependent and independent) and noticed most, if not all, variables are non-stationary. Therefore, I detrended and seasonally adjusted my dependent variable.

What I would like to do now is select the explanatory variables and select my model. Where I'm getting stuck/my questions are:

- What variable selection methods are there for time-series datasets? Do these variables need to be stationary before selection? I assume all of these variables should have some effect on the dependent variable but I would like to exclude those variables that have minimal/no effect

Comment: Welcome to CV! Just a note: "multivariate" = multiple **dependent variables**. "Multiple" (in a regression context" means multiple **independent** variables.

Comment: You could try the "Hierarchical Regression" approach, including the variables step by step and comparing which variables are significantly explaining the variations in your dependent variable. The variables should be stationary.